# Using L'Hopital's rule to find a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to determine if $z = \pi/6$ is a simple pole of the function
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 2 \sin z}.$$
Is it correct to evaluate
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \pi/6} \frac{z - \pi/6}{1 - 2 \sin z}$$
using L'Hopital's rule?  If L'Hopital's rule is used, the limit is $-1/\sqrt{3}$, 
which implies that $z = \pi/6$ is a simple pole.

Is this calculation correct?  If so, why can L'Hopital's rule be used when L'Hoptial's rule is only true for real valued functions, not complex valued functions?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You may want to read this http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2310244?uid=3738240&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104264474593

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct and it tells you that
$$
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\pi/6}\left(\frac1{1-2\sin(x)}\right)=-\frac1{\sqrt3}
$$
L'Hospital also works for [holomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) functions on $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

L`Hopital rule is an immediate consequence of the existence of the Taylor series. Anyhow, in this case you should simply observe that

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \pi/6} \frac{1 - 2 \sin z}{z - \pi/6}$$

is just the definition of the derivative of $f(z)=-2 \sin(z)$ at $\pi/6$.

Answer (score 0):

The point $z=\pi/6$ is a simple pole of $$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-2\sin(z)}$$ iff $z=\pi/6$ is a simple zero of $g(z) = 1-2\sin(z)$. A zero is simple if the derivative at that point is nonzero.

We know that $g'(z) = -2\cos(z)$ and $$g'(\pi/6) = -2\cos(\pi/6) = -\sqrt{3}.$$ Thus $z=\pi/6$ is a simple pole for $f$.

Comment: I know that this question really concerns l'Hopital's rule. However, you need to take the derivative of $1-2\sin(z)$ in either case.